# Find permutation minimizing distance

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

You have a square matrix of weights $W$ and a square matrix of distances $D$. You want to find a permutation $\sigma$ minimizing $$\sum_{i,j} W_{i,j} D_{\sigma(i), \sigma(j)}$$

Is there a known algorithm for that? Is the problem NP-complete? Is the optimal solution easily approximable?

Comment: If $D_{i,j} = |i-j|$ then we get minimum linear arrangement, a well-known NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be very close to the *minimum quadratic assignment problem*, see for example [a paper by Hassin, Levin and Sviridenko](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/s/sviri/papers/qa5.pdf); your problem is close to the metric variant (since $D$ is a metric). When $D_{i,j} = |i-j|$ we get the NP-hard problem *minimum linear assignment*, whose best known approximation ratio is $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{\log n})$.